# phpfox - what does Phpfox::getParam() do?

Tags: php, phpfox

I have emailed phpfox and they are taking their sweet time to email back, im just wondering what getParam() does? and also it seems to get settings e.g. Phpfox::getParam('user.approve_users') where are the settings held?? i cannot find them anywhere

Thanks for your help

:)

Comment: The very helpful Steward on the official phpFox forums answers [from where getParam() gets its values if they are not in the database](http://www.phpfox.com/forum/coding-developers-2/might-some-of-the-getparam-settings-not-be-in-the-database).

Answer (score 4):

are you familiar with API (and google.com ) ?

your answer is there :

http://www.phpfox.com/phpapi/Phpfox/Phpfox_Setting.html

> getParam (line 331)
>   Get a setting and its value.   return: Returns
>   the value of the setting, which can be a STRING, ARRAY, BOOL or INT.

just read the API

Comment: haha yes i read the api, but what is the setting? it doesnt state the settings properties or location

Comment: @Aiden The setting you specified.

Comment: i have not specified any settings, and if by chance im wrong, if i did where would they be located?

Comment: i guess what im trying to say is according to a framework everything must follow a certain pattern, and settings must be stored in a relevant place, but i have searched the direct modules e.g. getParam(user.do_something) i know where the "user" module is but i cannot locate the setting "do_something" anywhere within this module, i have searched the sorrounding modules and i am lost

Comment: @Aiden default settings. http://www.phpfox.com/phpapi/Phpfox/Phpfox_Setting.html#$_aDefaults
this is just default setting. perhaps they add many other setting into $_aParams

Comment: hmm i checked this file, its just database settings etc. not really custom settings, this is not my module it belongs with the initial install for phpfox, its just locating this settings file is impossible.. and if it is making reference to a child e.g. user.something then you would imagine the setting "something" would be inside the user module